# U-SQL CREATE DATA SOURCE for Azure SQL Server in US West region

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am trying to configure the firewall IP address whitelist access for an Azure SQL DB, in order to run a CREATE DATA SOURCE command for external U-SQL Data Lake Analysis querying. The guidance I am following is:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt763307.aspx

In there is a list for IP addresses per Azure data center region. The "US West" region is not listed, yet that is where my resource group is located.
So, the question is: What is the IP address range I should use for "US West" region?
Thank you!
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alex mentions, the IP range that you need to enable is the range for where your ADLA account resides. Since you are using Azure SQL DB, enabling Azure Services should be enough. If you were connecting to a SQL Server instance in the VM, you would need to enable the IP range as outlined in the documentation for the region where your ADLA account resides.

Having said that, please be aware that accessing data across region boundaries can be slow and you will have to pay for data egress for the data returned by Azure SQL DB to ADLA.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations!

Comment: You are welcome. Can you please mark the reply/replies as an answer?

Comment: OK, I think I did that. I am new to here. Looks like clicking the check mark does it, then it turns green. And looks like I can only mark one of them and an answer, since the UX only keeps one green check mark.

Answer (score 1):

You need the IP range for the region of your Data Lake Analytics account. Date Lake Analytics is not yet available in US West, so that can't be your region. Note that in the same resource group, you can have resources in multiple regions. Check the Overview pane of your Data Lake Analytics account for the correct region.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations!